# Unable to kill SPID

Tags: sql-server-2005, process

I have a SQL Server 2005 Std (x64) with SP4 that has a procedure I cannot seem to kill. If I view sys.dm_exec_requests I see SPID 103 with wait_type of LCK_M_SCH_M, a status of SUSPENDED and command of KILLED/ROLLBACK. However the SPID doesn't go away. I can even do sp_who 103 and I see the SPID with KILLED/ROLLBACK. The SPID has a current wait_time of almost 20 hours since I killed it.

Also, running `KILL 103 WITH STATUS ONLY` returns 0% completed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes a SPID can choke for some out of process calls.

- xp_sendmail (the old way)
- sp_OA%
- sp_xmlpreparedocument
- etc

You need to stop SQL Server or even reboot the server

Or more likely you could be rolling back a huge UPDATE or such: wait or restart, up to you...

Edit: Aaron's comment of changing a DB status may work as well as an intermediate step.

Comment: Okay, its just a small stored procedure not using a transaction.. not sure what hung it up so bad. I'll have to wait till my next maintenance cycle to restart. Thanks

Comment: If the SPID is connected to a specific database, you may be able to avoid a restart by setting that database `OFFLINE` or `SINGLE_USER` - `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` and then set the database back `ONLINE` or `MULTI_USER`. Might be worth a try if you can afford to blip the database for a moment but not the entire instance.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Yeah, I tried setting to SINGLE_USER and OFFLINE with ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE, but it just hangs and I have to stop the query. Thanks for the thought though!