# how can I see how many records have been affected by a transaction before it is committed? or how costly would be the rollback if I have to kill it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction, rollback, batch-processing

I am using [sqlwatch](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3164/22336) to monitor [some of my servers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/334222/22336) and it has a job that deletes in batch from a table called `dbo.sqlwatch_logger_snapshot_header`

I had lots of problems of locking and blocking as this table is used by different processes,
then I disabled all other jobs with the exception of the one that deals with this table.

I used the following script to disable all other sqlwatch jobs:

```
use distribution

set nocount on
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted

declare @Job_id uniqueidentifier
declare @job_name varchar(300)
declare @category_name varchar(300)
declare @body varchar(max)
declare @flag tinyint

declare @enabled bit = 0;  --0 - disable 1-enable
declare @subject varchar(300) = case when @enabled = 0 then 'Disabling  sqlwatch jobs on' + @@servername else 'Enabling sqlwatch jobs on' + @@servername end;
declare @job_enabled bit;

set @flag = 0
set @body = 'The following jobs are going to be ' +
          case when @enabled = 0 then 'Disabled' else 'Enabled' end
          + ' : '+char(10)+Char(13)


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.[dbo].[#LogReaderAgents]') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#LogReaderAgents] 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#LogReaderAgents] ( 
[job_id]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER                 NOT NULL,
[job_name]       SYSNAME                          NOT NULL,
[category_name]  SYSNAME                          NOT NULL,
[enabled]        TINYINT                          NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[#LogReaderAgents] ([job_id],[job_name],[category_name],[enabled])
select job_id, job_name = sj.name, category_name=sc.name, sj.enabled
from  msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
inner join msdb.dbo.syscategories sc
        on sj.category_id = sc.category_id
where 1=1
  and sj.name like 'SQLWATCH%'
 -- and sc.category_id in (10,13)
 and sj.name not in ('SQLWATCH-INTERNAL-RETENTION')

-- exec sp_gettabledef 'dbo.#LogReaderAgents'
-- exec sp_GetInsertList 'TEMPDB','DBO.#LogReaderAgents'


DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
       SELECT Job_id,job_name, category_name, [enabled]
       FROM #LogReaderAgents
OPEN c1
FETCH NEXT FROM c1
       INTO @Job_id,@job_name,@category_name,@job_enabled
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       begin

              if (select top (1) stop_execution_date from msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja
                     where Job_ID = @Job_id
                           and
                     ja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
                     order by Start_execution_date desc) is not NULL
              begin
                     set @flag = 1
                     Print @job_name +' is ' + case when @job_enabled=1 then 'Enabled' else 'disabled' end 
                     exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_id = @job_id, @enabled = @enabled
                     set @Body = @Body + char(10)+char(13) + @job_name + ' -- ' + @category_name +' is ' + case when @job_enabled=1 then 'Enabled' else 'disabled' end 
              end
              
              FETCH NEXT FROM c1
       INTO @Job_id,@job_name,@category_name,@job_enabled
       end
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

however, after that the job is still running, but I dont see any changes in the number of the records that are in this table.

here is the job executing a procedure and doing a delete in batch:

[image]

progress has been slow but steady, there were 37.2 million rows
[image]

now there are 36.9 millions

[image]

so basically it is working, so all good.

Now my question:

Suppose I had to stop this job for any reason,

it is a batch delete, if I had to stop this job now, how many rows are affected, how costly would it be to rollback what has not been committed yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions` to find out how much log has been written and therefore whether it needs to be rolled back.

```
select
  dt.database_transaction_log_bytes_used,
  dt.database_transaction_log_record_count,
  r.writes * 8 * 1024 as bytes_written
from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions dt
join sys.dm_tran_session_transactions tst on tst.transaction_id = dt.transaction_id
join sys.dm_exec_requests r on r.session_id = tst.session_id
where tst.session_id = @SomeSpidHere
  and dt.database_transaction_state <> 10;  -- not committed
```

Note that `database_transaction_log_record_count` is how many log records are generated, not how many rows are affected.

As to how long that data would take to rollback: who knows? It's very system dependent, and don't forget that rollbacks are single-threaded.